# How to exclude a method from an XA transaction with Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, transactions, hawq

I have a complex process that is designed to be transactional, and is coded to be tranactional with Spring annotations. When I run it against databases that have XA aware drivers, it works well (apart from the headache of setting up each RDBMS to support XA).

However, I am trying to hook it up to HAWQ.  HAWQ is XA aware to the point that it says, essentially, "Whoa Nellie, I don't do XA yet."  Since I am likely to run into other backing stores that have similar limitations, the exact exception is not important, only the concept that I need to support non-XA datastores in what is normally an XA context, within certain very coarse limits.

The process is structured so that XA is a valuable luxury, but transactional failures that are not captured in the XA scope are non-critical.

For the class that talks to HAWQ (or classes that touch other future non-XA systems), is there a way to annotate the method to say "I know the caller is transactional, but I am not."?

I have already reviewed [How to exclude a method to be @Transactional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248500/how-to-exclude-a-method-to-be-transactional), but it is solving a different problem.

```
class CallingClass
{
    @Transactional
    callingMethod ()
    {
        doSomeSetup ();
        methodFromWorkerClass();
    }
}

class NormalWorkerClass() implements Worker
{
    methodFromWorkerClass ()
    {
        doSomeStuff();
    }
}


class NonXAClass() implements Worker
{
    @INeedToBeNonXA
    methodFromWorkerClass ()
    {
        doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED would help? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html

Comment: Most XA providers allow you to have 1 non-XA resource in a JTA transaction. If you only expect a single one, configure your JTA provider accordingly. If you expect multiple of those resources for your application, you might want to reconsider JTA/XA altogether.

Comment: @HRgiger Per javadoc, Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED is supposed to suspend transactions so they can be resumed elsewhere, but suspend/resume is not a guaranteed feature of XA providers.  I thought this was my answer until the javadoc was read to me.

Comment: @M. Deinum The resources are configured dynamically at runtime.  Whether it's zero, one or many is a function of the target repositories. However, this points me in the direction of Quartz as a prototype, which requires both an XA and a non-XA datasource to function in the XA environment. My solution may be as simple as having the classes that talk to repositories that choke on XA instantiate their own non-XA connections (which I already have code for).